# Listing all users with DROP/DELETE privileges

Tags: mysql

How do I list all users who have DROP/DELETE privileges in mySQL?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from mysql.user where Delete_priv = 'Y' and Drop_priv = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use [show grants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html)

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

and see the users that have a delete/drop/all privileges

Answer (score 0):

Note, that user's privileges can be granted at some levels.

```
-- Global level privileges
SELECT CONCAT(user, '@', host) FROM mysql.user WHERE delete_priv = 'Y' OR drop_priv = 'Y'

-- Table level privileges
SELECT CONCAT(user, '@', host) FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE FIND_IN_SET('delete', table_priv) <> 0 OR FIND_IN_SET('drop', table_priv) <> 0
```

There also can be database level privileges (see mysql.db table).